# Setting up a percentage width to the Popup of an AutoSuggestBox

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal, autosuggest

I'm trying to customize the `Popup` of an `AutoSuggestBox`. I want it to have a width which is a **percentage** of the `TextBox`.

I suppose the only way I can accomplish this is by using a `Grid` and setting up the `ColumnDefinition` accordingly. The problem is that, even though the content of the `Popup` takes the width I want, there is a dark shadow in the remaining space:

[image]

Here's my XAML:

```
        <Style x:Key="CustomAutoSuggestBox" TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle" Value="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Landscape"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Portrait"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <TextBox
                                x:Name="TextBox"
                                ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"
                                Description="{TemplateBinding Description}"
                                DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge"
                                Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                Margin="0"
                                PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}"
                                UseSystemFocusVisuals="{TemplateBinding UseSystemFocusVisuals}"
                                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                Canvas.ZIndex="0" />
                            <Popup x:Name="SuggestionsPopup">
                                <Border x:Name="SuggestionsContainer">
                                    <!--The Grid that follows was created just so we
                                        can comply with GUI spec, which states that
                                        the suggestions box must be 75% of the
                                        search box.-->
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ListView
                                            x:Name="SuggestionsList"
                                            Background="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground}"
                                            BorderThickness="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListBorderThemeThickness}"
                                            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBorderBrush}"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                                            ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}"
                                            ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                            ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                            MaxHeight="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMaxHeight}"
                                            Margin="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMargin}"
                                            Padding="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListPadding}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I tried changing properties like `Background` for every parent of `Popup` in this template, but with no luck. I also tried moving the `Grid` component to outer controls, like the `Border` and so on.

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the following works, do you have any updates? And if the answer is helpful please consider mark it.

Comment: Hello @NicoZhu-MSFT, sorry for my delay. I had other stuff to attend to, but I'll get back to this as soon as I can. Thanks in advance for your answer, it does seem very promising. My only challenge is where I should declare the event handler, since the template is defined inside a resource dictionary, which does not support code-behind AFAIK.

Comment: May you need use visual tree helper to find SuggestionsContainer  then listen it's loaded event.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that, even though the content of the Popup takes the width I want, there is a dark shadow in the remaining space:

Please check [**Z-depth and shadow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/depth-shadow) document.

> ThemeShadow automatically casts shadows when applied to any XAML element in a Popup. It will cast shadows on the app background content behind it and any other open Popups below it.

If you want to disable it, the better way is that set `SuggestionsContainer` a new `Translation` in loaded event, and make z value as low enough.

For example:

```
private void SuggestionsContainer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var border = sender as Border;
    border.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, -100);
}
```